# AngularJS md-autocomplete is not displaying list of items

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am having a problem using Angular Material's autocomplete (md-autocomplete).  When retrieving data from the backend, the retrieved items are not shown in the frontend item list. Instead of showing the items, it is showing an X and clear button in the search field.

The following is a piece of code.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-5" >
    <label for="departure" style="font-size: 0.9rem; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 0.08rem; font-weight: 600; color: var(--light); transform: scale(1);">Departure Airport</label>
<md-autocomplete flex required
    md-no-cache="true"
    md-selected-item="preliminary.departureAirport"
    md-search-text="searchDeparture"
    md-items="item in doQueryAirport(searchDeparture)"
    md-item-text="item.display">
    <md-item-template class="">
        <span md-highlight-text = "searchDeparture">{{ item.display }}</span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

```js
function loadAllAirports(scope,http){
    http.get("rest/listairports").then(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 200 || response.status == 204) { 
            scope.airports = response.data.map(function (state) {
                return {
                  value: state.airportCountry.toLowerCase(),
                  display: state.airportCountry + " (" + state.airportIataCode + ")"
                };
              });
        } else {
            scope.airports = []
            console.log("Failed to list airports.");
        }
    });
}

function createFilterFor(query) {
    var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
    
    return function filterFn(state) {
      return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
    };
}

function queryAirport (query, scope, q, timeout) {
    var results = query ? scope.airports.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : scope.airports;
    var deferred = q.defer();
    timeout(function () { deferred.resolve(results); }, Math.random() * 1000, false);
    return deferred.promise;
}
var app = angular.module('homeApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope,$http, $q, $timeout) {
    initVars($scope);
    initView($scope);
    loadAllAirports($scope, $http);
    $scope.doClick=function(button) {click(button, $scope,$http);}
    $scope.doQueryAirport = function(query) {return queryAirport(query, $scope, $q, $timeout)}
});
```

The result it shows on the front is as follows (file attached):

Does anyone knows how can I fix it? I believe it's a problem on the frontend, because I can retrieve the data from de backend.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried to change the way I'm accessing the data in the front using the examples avalable at (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) changing the access using an specific controller. But the problem continues.